# If I select from an IQueryable then the Include is lost

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, include, anonymous-types

The `include` does not work after I perform a select on the `IQueryable` query.
Is there a way around this? My query is

```
public IQueryable<Network> GetAllNetworks()
{
    var query = (from n in _db.NetworkSet
                .Include("NetworkContacts.Contact")
                .Include("NetworkContacts.Contact.RelationshipSource.Target")
                .Include("NetworkContacts.Contact.RelationshipSource.Source")
                 select (n));        
    return query;;
}
```

I then try to populate my ViewModel in my WebUI layer using the following code

```
            var projectedNetworks =
            from n in GetAllNetworks()
            select new NetworkViewModel
            {
                Name = n.Name,
                Contacts = from contact in networkList
                    .SelectMany(nc => nc.NetworkContacts)
                    .Where(nc => nc.Member == true)
                    .Where(nc => nc.NetworkId == n.ID)
                    .Select(c => c.Contact)                        
                    select contact,
            };

        return projectedNetworks;
```

The problem now occurs in my newly created `NetworkViewModel`;
the `Contacts` collection objects do not include any loaded data for `RelationshipSource.Target` or `RelationshipSource.Source`.

However the data is there when run from the original Repository `IQueryable` method. However the related `include` data does not seem to get transferred into the new `Contacts` collection that is created when I use the `Select New NetworkViewModel {}`.

Is there a way to preserve this `Include` data when it gets passed into a new object? At the moment I just keep getting `Null` exceptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's an explanation of what's happening, with a workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include).

In your case, however, I think there's a *better* workaround than what's in that linked article. You're already using a view model for `Network`. That's good! Do it for contact (and it's related properties), too, and your problems with eager loading will magically go away. Projection *always* works.

Comment: Hi Craig - Thanks for the comment and link. Where should I use the ContactViewModel - Are you suggesting that I do a projection within a projction? Is that possible?