# Entity Framework not always including child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have a `User` that is assigned to a `Client`. When pulling out the `User` object, I get the `Client` object as part of it. Simple.

This works as it should when logging in. The `User` object has a `Client`, no matter who I log in as.

However, using the *exact* same method to get the `User` as when logging in, to edit it via the admin menus, the `Client` is sometimes `null`.

I say *sometimes*:

1) In Firefox - When attempting to view the details of *most*, but not all, users (and myself), the `Client` attached to the `User` will be `null`. Only a couple of the `Users` will be viewable due to the `Client` actually existing.

2) In Chrome - All users (EXCEPT myself) are visible. Only when attempting to view my own user will the `Client` be `null`.

I don't understand; Both browsers are simply going to the same URLs, i.e. `/Users/EditGet/28` and even using two different methods (`GetById` and `GetByUserName`) it provides the same results - though admittedly both make use of the base Get function:

Edit: The BaseService class together rather over edits.

```
internal CustomContext context;
internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

public BaseService(CustomContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet.Where(e => !e.Deleted);

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
}
```

I'm not sure why the choice of browser should affect the results of a back-end query at all. Surely it should return the `Client` with the `User` regardless of what browser I use.

I assume perhaps a basic fault with the base Get method, but it doesn't explain the behaviour that I'm seeing...

If anyone could shed any light on this, I would be most appreciative.

Edit 2:
CustomContext:

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext, ICustomContext
{
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Considering that all the code in question runs on the server i doubt that this is browser dependent - but it is as you observe so could it perhaps be that the `includeProperties` is a parameter passed to one of the mvc pages and is formatted incorrectly so that the split does not work?  Put a break point on the `query = query.Include(includeProperty);` line and see if it's alway hit

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt: Hits it every time. No issue with using the comma separation, it correctly hits it for each included property. Even the SQL generated by EF is correct (using SQL Profiler), and running the query returns everything it should, but the `Client` just isn't being generated and bound.

Comment: Why is variable query of type `IQueryable<TEntity>' instead of the expected `DbQuery<TEntity>`?  IQueryable<T> does not have an `Include` method so i don't see how this does not give a compile error on the .Include line

Comment: PTFC: paste the code - i see dbset is constructed elsewhere; please past at least where the dbset is constructed.  Maybe therein lies the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that the issue stems from the way we store the currently logged in `User`.

When attempting to retrieve another of that same `User` object, it then fails on also pulling out the `Client`.

Still not quite sure why this is. I've had a couple of hints that it has to do with the `Object State Manager` and tracking multiple objects - though the currently logged in `User` object isn't actually pulled from the DB...

What has fixed the issue, though, is do to a simple check to see if the `User` pulled out is the same as the currently logged in `User` and if the problem exists (the `Client` is `null`) then pull out the `Client` and attach it to the `User` object.

```
private User GetUser(long id)
{
    var user = Services.UserService.GetById(id);
    if (user.Client == null && CurrentUser.Id == user.Id)
        user.Client = Services.ClientService.GetByClient(CurrentUser.Client);

    return user;
}
```

Crude, and far from a decent answer as to how to properly work this problem out, but it works and all `User`s are fully editable once again.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to change from a comma separated list of includes - which may be prone to formatting bugs; you could change it to param or an array like such:

```
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                                                    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
                                                    params string[] includeProperties) {

            var query = ((DbQuery<TEntity>)dbset);

            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (q, s) => q.Include(s));

            query = query.Where(e => !e.IsDeleted);


            if (filter != null) {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }                

            return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
        }
```

I'm thinking that if it is browser dependent as you say there may be some string formatting issues... worth a shot anyway.

**EDIT**:  change query back to DbQuery

**EDIT2**: Fix is to put call to `Include` before the `Where` as `Include` must be called on the `DbSet` or `DbQuery`.  The reason it seemed random is that when there was no filter, then the includes were called on the DbSet/DbQuery where they were supposed to be.

Not easy to spot as the code had a call to `IQueryable<T>.Include`... which is not standard out of the box.  The `Include` is on the DbSet or DbQuery.

Comment: Thing is, I'm not passing any strings through browsers. At all. The URL only has the Id of the `User` and that's it. The `Client` include is a simple const string "Client", no other entities are associated with the `User` object and as mentioned, it works when logging in.

Comment: Yeah; well http://stackoverflow.com/a/2929109/1099260 answer has something that may be usefull.  I was also wondering, your query variable is of type `IQuerable<TEntity>` (instead of the exepected `DbQuery<TEntity>`.  IQueryable<T> does not have an `inlcude` method.

Comment: @Qinton Changing the includes to an array hasn't changed anything - but I think I'll keep it, I prefer it that way. As for why it's an `IQueryable`, I don't remember now. It was months ago that it was first put it and we've had no problems with it at all until recently. Not that any of us have changed it or any related code recently - the whole issue has us stumped at the moment. As a note, we are using EF5, if that makes a difference to our circumstances.

Comment: Yeah, but your code should only compile if you have written an `Include` extension method yourself for IQueryable<T> - this is normally for unit testing purposes....  change the type to `var query` or `DbQuery<TEntity> query` just as a try.  Won't hurt.

Comment: The `dbSet.Where...` returns an `IQueryable`, so using var seems pointless. Specifying `DbQuery` means all the `.Where`'s need to be cast. The result of which still does not change the outcome, unfortunately.

Comment: @Krenom: Ha! you just solved your own problem - The call to include has to be BEFORE the where.  So the reason why it seems random is that when there is no filter it'll work as the include is called first; else not. move the includes to before the fitler.

Comment: But when pulling out the `User`, there is *always* a filter for the `Client`. Also, it's doing a `Where` on the initialization: `var query = dbSet.Where(e => !e.Deleted);` which surely defeats the purpose of moving the include merely above the rest of the filters?

Comment: Where is the dbset being constructed? not in this method.  Oh, my edit was bad the include must be before the inital where as well. see edit.

Comment: [EF5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256692/linq-to-entities-include-method-not-found) seems to have the `Include` extensions available for `IQueryable`s, which would explain why it works against your expectations :)